# Make ActionHandler Ignore Arrow Keys

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How do I make Action Handler ignore arrow keys? Currently, when I try to use arrow keys to navigate my combo box, the combo box moves down/up once, changes the selection, and then triggers the Action Handler moving the focus to the button.
I would like to be able to navigate the combo box with the arrow keys, and hit Enter when I'm ready to move on to the next component.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {

JFrame window = new JFrame("testGUI");
JPanel windowPanel = new JPanel();

public static JLabel labelSize;
public static JComboBox<String> comboSize;

public static JLabel labelButton;
public static JButton buttonButton;

public test () {
    super();

    labelSize = new JLabel("Monster Size:");
    String[] sizeChoices = { "None", "Tiny", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Huge", "Colossal"};
    comboSize = new JComboBox<String>(sizeChoices);
    comboSize.setToolTipText("The creature's size.");
    comboSize.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                comboSize.showPopup();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            comboSize.showPopup();
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    });

    labelButton = new JLabel("Button:");
    buttonButton = new JButton();
    buttonButton.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                buttonButton.doClick();
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            buttonButton.doClick();
        }
    });


    windowPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    windowPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    windowPanel.add(labelSize);
    windowPanel.add(comboSize);
    windowPanel.add(labelButton);
    windowPanel.add(buttonButton);
    windowPanel.setVisible(true);

    window.setSize(500, 500);
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.add(windowPanel);

    comboSize.addActionListener(handler);
    buttonButton.addActionListener(handler);
}

ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();
public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eventFocus){
        if (eventFocus.getSource() == comboSize){
            buttonButton.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
        if (eventFocus.getSource() == buttonButton){
            comboSize.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test GUITest = new test();
}
}
```

Comment: You can implement the Focus in a KeyListener.

Comment: add ActionListener to JComboBox, to same with JButton, JButton#doClick() is about programatically fiiring an event without using mouse or keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the combo box moves down/up once, changes the selection, and then triggers the Action Handler moving the focus to the button. I would like to be able to navigate the combo box with the arrow keys, and hit Enter when I'm ready to move on to the next component.

You can set a property on the combo box to only generate the ActionEvent when Enter is pressed by using the following:

```
comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Complete example:

```
/*
    This works on non editable combo boxes
*/
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ComboBoxAction extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public ComboBoxAction()
    {
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.addActionListener( this );

        comboBox.addItem( "Item 1" );
        comboBox.addItem( "Item 2" );
        comboBox.addItem( "Item 3" );
        comboBox.addItem( "Item 4" );

        //  This prevents action events from being fired when the
        //  up/down arrow keys are used on the dropdown menu

        comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);

        getContentPane().add( comboBox );
        getContentPane().add( new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println( e.getModifiers() );

        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        System.out.println( comboBox.getSelectedItem() );

        //  make sure popup is closed when 'isTableCellEditor' is used

//      comboBox.hidePopup();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ComboBoxAction frame = new ComboBoxAction();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
     }
}
```

See [Combo Box No Action](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/combo-box-no-action/) for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to have a KeyListener in addition to this? When I try this with the comboBoxes in my code, hitting the arrow key doesn't trigger action events, but the arrow key is undone immediately afterward. For example, it would go down to highlight "Tiny", then instantly go back to "None". Holding the arrow key down allows going further down the list, but it will still always snap back to where it originally started.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't think to do this. I don't need to use KeyListener, or even hit any key for the combo box. I can just have the Action Handler do showPopup() automatically when the focus shifts to the combo box.