# Java - ActionEvent on jComboBox1 to update jComboBox2 - Keyboard/Mouse-Enter Key conditional

Tags: java, swing

I have two jComboBoxs, (1 and 2)

Based on the selection in 1 it updates 2.
The issue I'm facing is that the update on 2 gets done via a database query. So if someone selects the first combobox and starts typing to select what they want, it triggers the database query on every keypress / update to the selection. Which is not ideal.

One method around this is using the ActionEvent to test if it was selected with Mouse or Keyboard.

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    if (evt.getModifiers() == 0) {
        // Do nothing because keyboard is pressed
    } else {
        Object item = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        try{
        // DATABASE CONNECTION HERE
        // Load up jComboBox2
            jComboBox2.removeAllItems();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                jComboBox2.addItem(rs.getString(1));
            } 
            //Close and catch exceptions etc.
```

Is it possible to have a condition on the `}else{` to be able to say

`}else if(keyboardpressed(VK_ENTER) or mouseclick) {`

The reason being is that users will typically type to select in the first combobox and then press enter to select. Currently they have to reach for the mouse to select.

Comment: instead of `else { ...` make it `else if (<your_condition>) { ...` and remove completely remove the `else`. If the condition in `else if` won't be satisfied then nothing will be done. Also you can just make the required condition in first `if` without using `else if` or `else` proabaly.

Comment: Have you tried [item listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) instead of "action" listener?

Comment: You will have to use a KeyListener or something to do listen to keyboard input. There are also mouse listeners.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830825/make-actionhandler-ignore-arrow-keys/43834806#43834806. It shows how to only generate the ActionEvent when an item is selected by using the mouse or the Enter key.

Comment: @camickr This still outputs if you start typing I-T-E-M.

Comment: @KnowNoTrend Thanks, this helped me get to my solution. Using a KeyEvent and ActionEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a KeyEvent and an ActionEvent to populate the second comboBox

```
private void jComboBox1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      

    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        populateRoundNMS();
    }
}                                     

private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    if (evt.getModifiers() != 0) {
        populateRoundNMS();
    }
}  

private void populateRoundNMS(){
    //Run SQL and Populate jComboBox2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you shouldn't allow the query to happen from the **1st** combo-box unless the User selects a listed item or hits the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key on a ***valid*** text entry. Is there an auto-complete involved with your Combo-Box?. Perhaps even disable the **2nd** Combo-Box until a valid choice is made from the **1st** Combo-Box

Use the **ItemStateChanged** event instead:

```
 private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    // Prevent double selection from event.
    if(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        System.out.println(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
        // Or whatever you want to do with the selection.
    }
}
```

Comment: This still activates when the user types. EG. If there are Three options which can be selected from the drop down, "boat", "toast", "total". If the user selects the combo box and types T, O then it outputs "Toast". If the user types out T, O, T then the output is "Toast" "Total"